# Mount network drive - line 3 in /etc/fstab is bad

Tags: mount, fstab

I am a Ubuntu 12.04 novice and am seriously struggling to mount my network drive. 
I can see it in Nautilus, and its properties detail its name as 'Seagate Expansi'.
I have installed cifs, created the folder /media/public and added the line:

```
//192.168.1.1/Seagate Expansi /media/public cifs guest 0 0
```

...to etc/fstab. however when I run:

```
sudo mount -a
```

I receive the error:

```
line 3 in /etc/fstab is bad
```

I kind of understand what the error is telling me, but I don't understand where I have gone wrong. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: I think your problem is the space character between "Seagate" and "Expansi". Try using something without spaces in it - or try to enclose it in quotes.

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately it didnt work. I tried quotes - "seagate expansi", I tried seagate_expansi, seagateexpansi. In these cases I recieved "mount error(6): No such device or address"

Comment: # UNCONFIGURED FSTAB FOR BASE SYSTEM
/host/ubuntu/disks/swap.disk none swap sw 0 0
//192.168.1.1/seagate expansi /media/public cifs guest 0 0

Comment: Oooops my bad. It seems that quotes don't work in fstab. Try replacing the space with escape character notation.Space is \040

Comment: WooHooo !! Yep that sorted it instantly - thank you very much :)   I never would have found that on my own.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is a space character in the URL.

Since fstab does not allow use of quotes, you have to use the escape character notation. Use \040 to replace the space between "Seagate" and "expansi"